# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. with small batch size

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I have run into this error :
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 116.00 MiB (GPU 0; 7.80 GiB total capacity; 1.95 GiB already allocated; 110.00 MiB free; 2.00 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

However my batch size is already very small so I do not know what the problem is.

I am working on a Mask RCNN network.

When I use nvidia-smi to look at my GPU, this is the output.  :                                                                                                                       | NVIDIA-SMI 440.59       Driver Version: 440.59       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |

|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 20%   35C    P8     8W / 175W |   1260MiB /  7982MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|    0      5282      C   .../anaconda3/envs/deeplearning/bin/python  1249MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Thanks.

Comment: you need to provide more detail like the network structure and your GPU memory size

Comment: Most default maskrcnn implementations use large backbones that would make training with the total capacity you have impractical with batchsize more than 2. I would try changing the backbone to a smaller one.